# neo4j - restrict query based on node's rank

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a hierarchical structure of nodes, which all have a custom-assigned sorting property (numeric). Here's a simple Cypher query to recreate:

```
merge (p {my_id: 1})-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c1 { my_id: 11, sort: 100})
merge (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c2 { my_id: 12, sort: 200 })
merge (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c3 { my_id: 13, sort: 300 })
merge (c1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(cc1 { my_id: 111 })
merge (c2)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(cc2 { my_id: 121 })
merge (c3)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(cc3 { my_id: 131 });
```

The problem I'm struggling with is that often I need to make decisions based on child node rank relative to some parent node, with regads to this sort identifier. So, for example, node `c1` has rank 1 relative to node `p` (because it has the least `sort` property), `c2` has rank 2, and `c3` has rank 3 (the biggest `sort`).

The kind of decision I need to make based to this information: display children only of the first 2 `cX` nodes. Here's what I want to get:

[image: graph]

`cc1` and `cc2` are present, but `cc3` is not because `c3` (its parent) is not the first or the second child of `p`. Here's a dumb query for that:

```
match (p {my_id: 1 })-->(c)
optional match (c)-->(cc) where c.sort <= 200
return p, c, cc
```

The problem is, these `sort` properties are custom-set and imported, so I have no way of knowing which value will be held for child number 2.

My current solution is to rank it during import, and since I'm using Oracle, that's quite simple -- I just need to use `rank` window function. But it seems awkward to me and I feel like there could be more elegant solution to that. I tried the next query and it works, but it looks weird and it's quite slow on bigger graphs:

```
match (p {my_id: 1 })-->(c)
optional match (c)-->(cc) 
where size([ (p)-->(c1) where c1.sort < c.sort |c1]) < 2
return p, c, cc
```

Here's the plan for this query and the most expensive part is in fact the `size` expression:

[image: query plan]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowness you're seeing is likely because you're not performing an index lookup in your query, so it's performing an all nodes scan and accessing the `my_id` property of every node in your graph to find the one with id 1 (your `p` node).

You need to add labels on your nodes and use these labels in your queries (at least for your `p` node), and create an index (or in this case, probably a unique constraint) on the label for `my_id` so this lookup becomes fast.

You can confirm what's going on by doing a PROFILE of your query (if you can add the profile plan to your description, with all elements of the plan expanded that would help determine further optimizations).

As for your query, something like this should work (I'm using a :Node label as a standin for your actual label)

```
match (p:Node {my_id: 1 })-->(c)
with p, c
order by c.sort asc
with p, collect(c) as children // children are in order
unwind children[..2] as child  // one row for each of the first 2 children
optional match (child)-->(cc)  // only matched for the first 2 children
return p, children, collect(cc) as grandchildren
```

Note that this only returns nodes, not paths or relationships. The reason why you're getting the result graph in the graphical view is because, in the Browser Setting tab (the gear icon in the lower left menu) you have `Connect result nodes` checked at the bottom.

Comment: thank you very much for expanded response, I've added the profiling plan to my question. In fact actual DB has needed indexes and labels as you can see in the plan, and the most expensive part of the plan is in fact that clause with size. Having said that, your query is very performant, so I would say that does the trick! Thanks again!